# Using Jolt to filter results

Tags: json, jolt

Given the following input:

```json
[
  {
    "order": "SI867-5309"
  },
  {
    "order": ""
  },
  {
    "order": "SI555-1212"
  },
  {
    "order": {
      "status": "Bad"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to use jolt to translate to :

```json
[
  {
    "order": "SI867-5309"
  },
  {
    "order": "SI555-1212"
  }
]
```

I have gotten close with:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "order": {
          "SI*": "@1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but thats not it, because it although it does filter out the values starting with SI, it then makes the values into the keys.  I think I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're so close to the result, just replace `"@1"` with `{ "$": "[].&2" }`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "order": {
          "SI*": {
            "$": "[].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `"$"` operator matches the **key**, `&2` matches the **value** and prepending `&2` with `[].` is used to seperate the elements respectively.